# Git: Pulling from Remote by Tag

Tags: git, version-control

I'm a beginner at git and have been testing a couple of commands on my local computer by creating a local repository to pull and push from and to.

I setup a bare repository in 'project' and cloned two users: 'user1' and 'user2' from it. The project currently has the files 'one.txt', 'two.txt' etc. and a few commits tagged with 'v1.0', 'v2.0' etc. associated with adding a new "#.txt" file.

However, when I attempt to create a new git working directory in a new folder 'tmp', adding the project as a remote repository (tmp is not a clone), and pulling, I get the error:

```
$ git pull ../project v1.0
$ fatal: 'v1.0' does not appear to be a git repository
$ fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This doesn't happen when I simply try to pull the master branch from project, so I assume I have permissions to pull. What's going on?

Comment: You seem to be coming from an SVN background. Forget everything you know and start from scratch.

Comment: I have no background at all. I'm simply copying what my instructors do on school machines to retrieve homework that I submit by pushing tagged commits. It seems to work perfectly fine on their machines. Replicating at home seems to yield different results.

Answer (score 4):

All you want to do is create another clone. Unless you have good reason not to do it, it will duplicate all history (don't worry, it's usually <10% the size of an svn repo and often smaller than the working dir due to compression).

Create your first repo:

```
mkdir myrepo
cd !$
git init
echo one > one.txt
git add -A
git commit "my first commit"
git tag v1.0
echo two > two.txt
git add -A
git commit "my second commit"
git tag v2.0
```

Create a simulated central repo:

```
cd ..
mkdir centralrepo
cd !$
git init --bare # don't want to have a working directory here
cd -
```

Create a simulated coworker repo:

```
mkdir coworkerrepo
cd !$
git init
```

Tell your repo where the central repo is

```
cd ../myrepo
git remote add origin ../centralrepo
```

Tell your coworker's repo where the central repo is

```
cd ../coworkerrepo
git remote add origin ../centralrepo
```

Publish your work to the central repo:

```
cd - # useful shortcut for flipping between two dirs (works for git checkout and branches too)
git push origin master
```

puts up the master reference and the commits within, but not tags. For tags, do this:

```
git push origin v1.0
git push origin v2.0
```

or just push up all tags in your repo with

```
git push origin --tags
```

you can now check that the remote has those tags and references with

```
git remote -v show origin
```

switch to your coworker's repository and get those changes:

```
cd -
git fetch # will update tracking branches and tags
git merge origin/master # fast-forward master branch to what the remote tracking branch is pointing to
```

the two operations `fetch` and `merge` are done at the same time with `pull`. So you could have done this instead

```
git pull origin master
```

So tags get fetched. This is implied when you realize that pull is fetch and merge (or rebase if you want) put together.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I want to create a new git directory, tmp, with git initialized within it and pull from a remote directory by a tag instead of a branch. It's supposed to work but I'm getting that error for some reason.

Comment: You don't understand what pull means. You can't "pull by tag". I'll edit the answer to show you how to do what you want.

Comment: I understand the basic system of pulling and pushing. Yes, cloning and ordinary push/pull/fetch operations work fine. I'm wondering why pulling by tag does not.

At my school the process for submitting assignments is by tagging a commit and pushing it to a repository assigned to us. Then, in order to retrieve the assignment, my instructors simply "git pull <my_repo> hw1" where hw1 is a tag. It works then. It seems not to work on my own homemade repository.

Comment: If all of you are using the same tag, they simply iterate through each remote to get each tag. They would do something like `git tag -l | xargs git tag -d` in between each to clear out previous versions. Maybe they have their own tags on their side to track your past work. Who knows. Ask them.

Comment: That would make sense...if I couldn't do the same thing myself. The only steps I do is: make a new directory called "tmp", git init inside that directory. Add my repository that I upload hw to as origin. "git pull origin hw1" to pull my hw1 commit. 

That's all I do and it works. However, judging from your responses, it shouldn't. Which leaves me perplexed.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the tags in your history. You can use `git tag -l` to list all available tags, and you can `git checkout` to them at any time.

```
git checkout v1.0
```

Comment: tmp is a new directory, initialized with 'git init'. I added the project repository as a remote named 'origin', but 'tmp' isn't a clone so it doesn't have any tags or files in it. I'm trying to see if I can pull from remote by tag instead of by branch.

Sorry if I was unclear, I edited my original post to reflect it.

Comment: Ah- in that case, no, you cannot pull by tag. That isn't quite what tags are for anyway, as somebody else has said, you seem to be coming from SVN. Git is very different, and, once you're used to it, much nicer.

Comment: I see. In this case I wonder why it works on my school's git system. The only reason why I'm attempting this is because my school has us push our homework/projects to a central repo tagged with the type of assignment "hw1", "proj1" and then has us test if we submitted properly by creating a new git directory and applying the command: 'git pull origin hw1'. It works on school computers, but it seems not to on my own test repository.

Comment: Strange, so are you saying the school automatically creates branches for my tags? How I upload homework is by adding the "hw1" folder/files to my master branch. Commit the changes. Tag the commit with "hw1". Then apply "git push origin master". 

To retrieve the code (check I uploaded it correctly), I create a separate temporary directory that I initialize with git and add the remote "origin". Then run "git pull origin hw1" and my homework files/folders are instantly downloaded.

Comment: It is really weird that that works. I'm almost wondering if they have some weird aliases set up, but I don't even think that it's possible to do that... Sorry that I couldn't help, but this is beyond me. If you end up asking your teacher how that works, be sure to report back, I'm really curious as to what they have going on there.